# How to properly configure system to remotely launch nodes

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remote-launch, ssh, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having trouble launching nodes remotely using launch files and need some help. Even using ssh keys `roslaunch` still cannot find the remote computer (despite it stating that it started the `ssh` session). I'm running Indigo with Ubuntu 14.04 on both my workstation computer and the computer aboard the robot, I'm not setting any parameters, and I don't have `ROS_HOSTNAME` set, only `ROS_IP` which is `192.168.1.103` for the workstation (master) and `192.168.1.212` for the robot. These are the steps that have been taken so far:

1. Went through the [ROS Network Setup Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) and made sure that the machines can ping each other and used `netcat` to check that communication over ports is possible.
2. Create an RSA ssh key to make it possible to ssh into a machine without a password (and checked it).
3. Used `ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms='ssh-rsa' host` when making the first connection as shown in this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/41446/a-is-not-in-your-ssh-known_hosts-file/?answer=42629#post-id-42629)
4. Followed the example in the [`roslaunch` `machine` tag wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/machine#Examples).
5. Tried using the [`ROSLAUNCH_SSH_UNKNOWN` environment variable](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Commandline%20Tools#Environment_Variables_.28advanced_users.29)
6. Tried steps 4 and 5 with a DSA key, but still no luck.

The robot can still be `ssh`ed into and can have code run from there and everything works normally (can see data coming in from topics from the robot, etc.) so I don't think that it's a network issue (although it could be). It's just the launching using `machine` tags that doesn't work. Here's the test launch file (`talker.launch`) that I've been using:

```
<launch>
    <machine name="robot" user="ngcneuro" address="red2" default="true" env-loader="/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh"/>
    <node pkg="beginner_tutorials" name="talker" type="talker.py" machine="robot" />
</launch>
```

My package is called `test_machine` and here's what `ROS master` is telling me after running:

`$ roslaunch test_machine talker.launch`

```
... logging to /home/ngcneuro/.ros/log/7ce15492-50a4-11e7-8d3e-40167e358fbd/roslaunch-NGNeuromorphic1-14982.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://192.168.1.103:59087/
remote[red2-0] starting roslaunch
remote[red2-0]: creating ssh connection to red2:22, user[ngcneuro]
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py:141: FutureWarning: CTR mode needs counter parameter, not IV
  self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
launching remote roslaunch child with command: [env ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.103:11311 /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh roslaunch -c red2-0 -u http://192.168.1.103:59087/ --run_id 7ce15492-50a4-11e7-8d3e-40167e358fbd]
remote[red2-0]: ssh connection created

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.21

MACHINES
 * robot

NODES
  /
    talker (beginner_tutorials/talker.py)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.103:11311

core service [/rosout] found
^C[red2-0] killing on exit
^Cerror launching on [red2-0, uri http://robot:39508/]: Interrupted system call
Launch of the following nodes most likely failed: beginner_tutorials/talker.py
^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^X^X^X^C^C^C^Cremote[red2-0]: unable to contact [red2] to shutdown remote processes!
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

It takes several minutes to regain control of the terminal, even after using `Ctrl-C` several times. And here's my `roslaunch` log:

```
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,124: Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,130: Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,131: roslaunch starting with args ['/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roslaunch', 'test_machine', 'talker.launch']
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,132: roslaunch env is {'CPU_ONLY': '0', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/', 'XDG_SESSION_ID': 'c2', 'MANDATORY_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path', 'CUDA_MINOR_NUM': '5', 'COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE': 'ubuntu', 'CARLSIM_FASTMATH': '0', 'JOB': 'dbus', 'SESSION': 'ubuntu', 'XMODIFIERS': '@im=ibus', 'JAVA_HOME': '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle', 'TURTLEBOT_INTERACTIONS_LIST': '[turtlebot_bringup/admin.interactions, turtlebot_bringup/documentation.interactions, turtlebot_bringup/pairing.interactions, turtlebot_bringup/visualisation.interactions]', 'SELINUX_INIT': 'YES', 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1000', 'PYTHONPATH': '/home/ngcneuro/ca_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/:/home/ngcneuro/opt/nest/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 'COMPIZ_BIN_PATH': '/usr/bin/', 'J2SDKDIR': '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle', 'ROS_ROOT': '/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros', 'CUDA_INSTALL_PATH': '/usr/local/cuda-6.5', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-MzFRSBiRBN', 'ORBIT_SOCKETDIR': '/tmp/orbit-ngcneuro', 'DEFAULTS_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path', 'DESKTOP_SESSION': 'ubuntu', 'GTK_MODULES': 'overlay-scrollbar:unity-gtk-module', 'INSTANCE': '', 'TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE': '/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world', 'TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR': 'asus_xtion_pro', 'TURTLEBOT_RAPP_PACKAGE_BLACKLIST': '[]', 'XDG_MENU_PREFIX': 'gnome-', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'TURTLEBOT_TYPE': 'turtlebot', 'BASH_FUNC_module%%': '() {  eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`\n}', 'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID': 'this-is-deprecated', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', 'TURTLEBOT_MAP_FILE': '/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_navigation/maps/willow-2010-02-18-0.10.yaml', 'CPATH': '/home/ngcneuro/ca_ws/devel/include:/opt/ros/indigo/include', 'USER': 'ngcneuro', 'XDG_VTNR': '7', 'CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH': '/home/ngcneuro/ca_ws/devel:/opt/ros/indigo', 'AMDAPPSDKROOT': '/opt/AMDAPP', 'XAUTHORITY': '/home/ngcneuro/.Xauthority', 'LANGUAGE': 'en_US', 'SESSION_MANAGER': 'local/NGNeuromorphic1:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2896,unix/NGNeuromorphic1:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2896', 'CARLSIM_LIB_DIR': '/opt/CARL/CARLsim', 'QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME': 'appmenu-qt5', 'DISPLAY': ':0', 'CLUTTER_IM_MODULE': 'xim', 'WINDOWID': '56623108', 'GPG_AGENT_INFO': '/run/user/1000/keyring-S68IVz/gpg:0:1', 'MODULESHOME': '/usr/share/modules', 'GDMSESSION': 'ubuntu', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'XDG_SEAT_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0', 'ROS_PACKAGE_PATH': '/home/ngcneuro/ca_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks', 'TURTLEBOT_BASE': 'kobuki', '_': '/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roslaunch', 'MODULEPATH': '/etc/environment-modules/modules:/usr/share/modules/versions:/usr/Modules/$MODULE_VERSION/modulefiles:/usr/share/modules/modulefiles', 'GTK_IM_MODULE': 'ibus', 'XDG_CONFIG_DIRS': '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg', 'TURTLEBOT_BATTERY': '/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0', 'TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_MAP_FILE': '/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/maps/playground.yaml', 'ROS_MASTER_URI': 'http://192.168.1.103:11311', 'COLORTERM': 'gnome-terminal', '_LMFILES_': '/usr/share/modules/modulefiles/zds/zds-1.1.0.60', 'CARLSIM_CUOPTLEVEL': '3', 'MODULE_VERSION': '3.2.10', 'XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR': '/var/lib/lightdm-data/ngcneuro', 'QT4_IM_MODULE': 'xim', 'TERMINATOR_UUID': 'urn:uuid:54cc3f7f-1b2b-40a6-b68f-8f0873775c0a', 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH': '/home/ngcneuro/ca_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig', 'ROS_IP': '192.168.1.103', 'ZDS_ROOT': '/opt/qualcomm/zeroth/zds-1.1.0.60', 'HOME': '/home/ngcneuro', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/home/ngcneuro/ca_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/indigo/lib:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64:/opt/qualcomm/zeroth/zds-1.1.0.60/lib:/opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64:/opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86:/usr/local/lib', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'ROS_LOG_FILENAME': '/home/ngcneuro/.ros/log/7ce15492-50a4-11e7-8d3e-40167e358fbd/roslaunch-NGNeuromorphic1-14982.log', 'TURTLEBOT_SIMULATION': 'false', 'TEXTDOMAIN': 'im-config', 'CUDA_HOME': '/usr/local/cuda-6.5', 'ROSLAUNCH_SSH_UNKNOWN': '0', 'TURTLEBOT_SERIAL_PORT': '/dev/kobuki', 'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP': 'Unity', 'TURTLEBOT_NAME': 'turtlebot', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'GNOME_KEYRING_PID': '2690', 'ROS_ETC_DIR': '/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros', 'J2REDIR': '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre', 'ROS_DISTRO': 'indigo', 'CARLSIM_CUDAVER': '6.5', 'ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES': '/home/ngcneuro/ca_ws/devel/share/common-lisp', 'QT_IM_MODULE': 'ibus', 'LOGNAME': 'ngcneuro', 'XDG_SEAT': 'seat0', 'GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL': '/run/user/1000/keyring-S68IVz', 'PATH': '/opt/ros/indigo/bin:/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/:/opt/qualcomm/zeroth/zds-1.1.0.60/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin', 'TERM': 'xterm', 'XDG_SESSION_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0', 'TURTLEBOT_STACKS': 'hexagons', 'TURTLEBOT_RAPP_PACKAGE_WHITELIST': '[rocon_apps, turtlebot_rapps]', 'SESSIONTYPE': 'gnome-session', 'IM_CONFIG_PHASE': '1', 'GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID': '31090', 'GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE': '/usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop', 'MODULE_VERSION_STACK': '3.2.10', 'CUDA_MAJOR_NUM': '3', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/run/user/1000/keyring-S68IVz/ssh', 'TEXTDOMAINDIR': '/usr/share/locale/', 'DERBY_HOME': '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db', 'UPSTART_SESSION': 'unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/2693', 'OLDPWD': '/home/ngcneuro/ca_ws/src/test_laser', 'LOADEDMODULES': 'zds/zds-1.1.0.60', 'GDM_LANG': 'en_US', 'SHLVL': '1', 'PWD': '/home/ngcneuro/ca_ws/src/test_machine'}
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,132: starting in server mode
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,132: starting roslaunch parent run
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,133: loading roscore config file /opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros/roscore.xml
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,355: Added core node of type [rosout/rosout] in namespace [/]
[roslaunch.config][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,355: loading config file /home/ngcneuro/ca_ws/src/test_machine/launch/talker.launch
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,357: Added node of type [beginner_tutorials/talker.py] in namespace [/]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,357: ... selected machine [robot] for node of type [beginner_tutorials/talker.py]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,370: start_process_monitor: creating ProcessMonitor
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,371: created process monitor <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, initial daemon)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,371: start_process_monitor: ProcessMonitor started
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,371: starting parent XML-RPC server
[roslaunch.server][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,371: starting roslaunch XML-RPC server
[roslaunch.server][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,372: waiting for roslaunch XML-RPC server to initialize
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,372: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0:0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,373: Started XML-RPC server [http://192.168.1.103:59087/]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,373: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,385: started roslaunch server http://192.168.1.103:59087/
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,385: ... parent XML-RPC server started
[roslaunch.remote][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,386: remote[red2-0] starting roslaunch
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,386: remote[red2-0] starting roslaunch
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,386: remote[red2-0]: creating ssh connection to red2:22, user[ngcneuro]
[roslaunch.remoteprocess][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,387: remote[red2-0]: invoking with ssh exec args [/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh roslaunch -c red2-0 -u http://192.168.1.103:59087/ --run_id 7ce15492-50a4-11e7-8d3e-40167e358fbd]
[paramiko.transport][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,428: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.6.1p1)
[paramiko.transport][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,555: Authentication (publickey) successful!
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,574: launching remote roslaunch child with command: [env ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.103:11311 /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh roslaunch -c red2-0 -u http://192.168.1.103:59087/ --run_id 7ce15492-50a4-11e7-8d3e-40167e358fbd]
[paramiko.transport][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,674: Secsh channel 1 opened.
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,678: remote[red2-0]: ssh connection created
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,679: ProcessMonitor.register[red2-0]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:26,679: ProcessMonitor.register[red2-0] complete
[roslaunch.server][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:27,177: child [red2-0] registered with server, uri[http://robot:39508/]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:27,181: master.is_running[http://192.168.1.103:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:27,184: master.is_running[http://192.168.1.103:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:27,186: ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.103:11311
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:27,190: setting /roslaunch/uris/host_192_168_1_103__59087' to http://192.168.1.103:59087/
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:27,195: load_parameters starting ...
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:27,199: ... load_parameters complete
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:27,200: launch_nodes: launching local nodes ...
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:57:27,200: launch_nodes: launching remote nodes ...
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:59:30,777: ProcessMonitor.shutdown <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 139629411092224)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:59:30,799: ProcessMonitor._post_run <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 139629411092224)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:59:30,799: ProcessMonitor._post_run <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 139629411092224)>: remaining procs are [<roslaunch.remoteprocess.SSHChildROSLaunchProcess object at 0x7efe01b43850>]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:59:30,800: ProcessMonitor exit: killing red2-0
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 18:59:30,800: [red2-0] killing on exit
[roslaunch.pmon][ERROR] 2017-06-13 18:59:50,778: shutdown_process_monitor: ProcessMonitor shutdown failed!
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2017-06-13 19:00:05,826: error launching on [red2-0, uri http://robot:39508/]: Interrupted system call
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2017-06-13 19:00:05,827: Launch of the following nodes most likely failed: beginner_tutorials/talker.py
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:00:05,827: ... launch_nodes complete
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:00:05,827: registrations completed <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 139629411092224)>
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:00:05,827: ... roslaunch parent running, waiting for process exit
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:00:05,828: spin
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2017-06-13 19:03:45,303: remote[red2-0]: unable to contact [red2] to shutdown remote processes!
[roslaunch.remoteprocess][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:03:45,303: remote[red2-0]: closing ssh connection
[roslaunch.remoteprocess][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:03:45,303: remote[red2-0]: ssh connection closed
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:03:45,304: ProcessMonitor exit: cleaning up data structures and signals
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:03:45,304: ProcessMonitor exit: pmon has shutdown
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:03:45,368: process monitor is done spinning, initiating full shutdown
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:03:45,368: runner.stop()
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:03:45,368: shutting down processing monitor...
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:03:45,368: shutting down processing monitor <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, stopped daemon 139629411092224)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:03:45,368: ProcessMonitor.shutdown <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, stopped daemon 139629411092224)>
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:03:45,369: ... shutting down processing monitor complete
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:03:45,369: done
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:03:45,369: ProcessMonitor.shutdown <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, stopped daemon 139629411092224)>
[rospy.core][INFO] 2017-06-13 19:03:45,369: signal_shutdown [atexit]
```

Contents of the `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   NGNeuromorphic1
192.168.1.175   red1
192.168.1.212   red2
192.168.1.208   yellow
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263798/how-to-properly-configure-system-to-remotely-launch-nodes/) by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6155 on 2017-06-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your ssh connection is connecting.

I believe that your problem is that your robot's hostname is 'robot' and that is not resolvable on the robot.

```
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2017-06-13 16:09:14,455: error launching on [address-0, uri http://robot:47383/]: No route to host
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2017-06-13 16:09:14,456: Launch of the following nodes most likely failed: beginner_tutorials/talker.py
```

When you say that you checked that you could ping each other. Did you check that you can ping yourself?

```
ping `hostname`
```

You can create a custom env file on the robot that sets things like ROS_HOSTNAME as well as sourcing the setup.bash. Or you can resolve the hostname resolution.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-06-13**:
I've tried the hostname with a number of different names (red, yellow, etc.) along with different names for the address and user and have had the exact same results. I can also ping myself as well.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-06-13**:
Can you explain what you mean by red and yellow? Can you provide a non-sanitized output? One of the machines cannot ping itself. And remember that when you ssh like this you don't get your ~/.bashrc.

```
ssh user@address ping \`hostname\`
ssh user@address ping robot
```

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-06-13**:
red and yellow are just names I have in my hosts file that I use to map to IP addresses within my network (based on the color of the robot). I was able to ping back and forth before so I never tried what you suggested. I pinged myself as you suggested and I get `connect: Network is unreachable`

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-06-13**:
Disregard the last comment. I had a misspelling in my command. I can ping myself without any problems.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-06-13**:
Please provide the actual outputs from the commands you run with all the variations. Without that I can't do much to help you. You can edit your question to add more details. Share what are your hostnames, what's in /etc/hosts? What are the parameters your setting?Otherwise I can't help you debug.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-06-13**:
Thanks for the update. As you can see the error is that it's still trying to contact `robot` You mention that you're setting ROS_IP, but you're using the stock indigo/env.sh You either need to change the hostname to or create a custom env script which will set the ROS_IP on the remote machine.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-06-14**:
Thank you very much for patiently walking me through all of this, it's now working. I did what you said: created a script to set the `ROS_IP` and `ROS_MASTER_URI` on the remote machine and sources the `devel/setup.bash` script.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-06-14**:
Funny thing that's happening now is that after I stop the launch file (using `Ctrl-C` ) I can see that the nodes are still running by using `rosnode list` and I can't start up another `roscore/master` as it says that one is still running despite me not seeing one running in my terminal.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-06-14**:
I also used [this](https://github.com/pandora-auth-ros-pkg/pandora_docs/wiki/Remote-Machines-Running-ROS-nodes) as extra resource to help get everything running.